# How to use JpegTran to recursively process all images, overwriting them, in a directory using Windows?

Tags: windows, image-processing, command-line, batch-file

Right now I have the following batch file that I use to process my images:

```
@echo none 
cd %1 
md "%~1\ProcessedJPEGS"
for %%i in (*.jpg) do "C:\Program Files\Image Optimization\jpegtran.exe" -optimize -progressive -copy none "%%i" "%~1\ProcessedJPEGS\%%i" 
move /Y "%~1\ProcessedJPEGS\*.*" "%~1" 
rd "%~1\ProcessedJPEGS" 
pause
```

As you can see, this is not ideal but my skills are laughable at best so I need some help here :)

What I want to accomplish is to run this batch in a directory and process all images recursively and overwrite them.

Thanks in advance,
Arky

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Oh, sorry for not mentioning. Windows 8 Pro x64

Comment: What do you mean with `recursively`? Are there subfolders?

Comment: Yes, right now I need to execute the bat on each folder.

Ideally I would like to run it once from the root folder and let the script parse everything recursively, overwriting the files with optimized versions.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. You can do this easily with a `for /r` loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based upon your command line, this should process all JPG files from the current folder and below.  Test it on a sample set of files/folders to be sure it works for you.

```
@echo none 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "*.jpg" /b /s /a-d') do (
echo processing "%%a"
"C:\Program Files\Image Optimization\jpegtran.exe" -optimize -progressive -copy none "%%a" "%%a.tmp"
move /Y "%%a.tmp" "%%a" >nul
)
pause
```

Comment: Depending on the jpegtran version used (if you see your console flooded with text, for example if the libjpeg-turbo is used), you'd have to replace `"%%a" "%%a.tmp"` with `"%%a" > "%%a.tmp"`.