# How to Set Up & Use Jpegtran with Windows

Tags: windows, image-processing, command-line, batch-file

I am a Windows user trying to get started with jpegtran and have not found a way to actually access the program.  All questions I've found start at the command line, but when trying to duplicate the commands, I receive errors such as the following:

After viewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186885/how-to-use-jpegtran-to-recursively-process-all-images-overwriting-them-in-a-di):

I tried to run these commands:

```
@echo none 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "*.jpg" /b /s /a-d') do (
echo processing "%%a"
"C:\Program Files\Image Optimization\jpegtran.exe" -optimize -progressive -copy none "%%a" "%%a.tmp"
move /Y "%%a.tmp" "%%a" >nul
)
pause
```

I get the error "%%a was not expected at this time."

My question is how to set up the folder structure for the images, jpegtran.exe file and the command prompt so that this command will run?

Comment: Your solution above looks to have correct format - but it is a batch file and you cannot paste it into a command prompt.  Save the code in a text file, call it `runjpg.bat` and launch it in a folder with some jpg files to test.  (Avoid calling the batchfile the same name as a command)

Comment: @foxidrive, thank you. This works perfectly. Please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution above looks to have correct format - but it is a batch file and you cannot paste it into a command prompt. Save the code in a text file, call it `runjpg.bat` and launch it in a folder with some jpg files to test. (Avoid calling the batchfile the same name as a command)

Comment: And for anyone else who wants to know, to run `runjpg.bat` all you have to do is drag and drop it into the command prompt and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

[Wrong information removed]

EDIT:

Sorry, didn't REALLY saw question!

This batch corrected will, for each jpg file found in current directory and subdirectories:

- create a optimized file (suffixed .tmp)
- replace original file with tmp file created.

Only requirement I see here is that you must have `jpegtran.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Image Optimization` folder!

Comment: Is this meant to be inputted in the command line as one line or as separate lines?

Comment: I have the folder structure as follows:  created a folder in C:\Program Files called Image Optimization and inputted the jpegtran.exe file and images there, and opened the command line from the Image Optimization folder.  When running the script as one line, the command returns no errors but does not perform any actions either.

Comment: to run from command line you must replace all `%%a` with `%a`

Comment: Tried that also, still no errors but no actions performed either. I checked my images in the folder and they are the exact same size.

Comment: I guess my problem is that I am missing the "basics" when it comes to running a script like this. Would you be able to point me somewhere where I can learn the basics of doing this type of thing?

Comment: No, as soon as I enter the script, the command prompt is ready for a new command.  I do have the jpegtran.exe in the C:\Program Files\Image Optimization folder

Comment: Try `for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir "*.jpg" /b /s /a-d') do echo %a` Do you get jpgs full pathnames?

Comment: Nevermind, that was because I had removed the images somewhere else. I placed the images back and it returns image file names.

Comment: `"tokens=*"` removes reading whitespace leading to errors when filenames have leading spaces.  `"delims="` doesn't do anything like you describe - it disables delimiters altogether and returns the entire input line.

Comment: @LS_dev, I believe the problem was that I had to run this command as a .bat file and not enter it manually in the command line. I saved the command to a file call runjpg.bat and drag and dropped the .bat file into the command prompt and it worked like a charm.  I do appreciate your help!